# AFNetworking HTTP POST not working, no error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios7, afnetworking-2

I'm using the following code:

```
[manager POST:@"https://url.html" parameters:postParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"rO: %@", responseObject);
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }];
```

When I run it, there is no output. Even when I put in breakpoints in both the success and failure portions, the program does not stop. I do not get any errors, either.

What could be happening here? I don't get any console output whatsoever, and no errors... I am lost on what to do.

Comment: Nope, manager isn't nil.

Answer (score 0):

check respone data , AFNetworking not support application "text/html" data. you can this URL test  "http://yoopin.com.cn/share/lsgo/api_lsgo/register"

Comment: I think you might not have understood the question.  The success/failure blocks are not getting called.  How will the OP check the response data?